# C# How To Have Stable SendKeys Function

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I’m Trying To Implement An AutoTyper Into My Personal Application But There’s Minor Issues Or Flaws.

Using Regex I’m Replacing The Characters Which Have Special Meanings Within Brackets So It Can Send The Key Raw. +, ^, %, ( & ), { & } Are Enclosed In Curly Brackets.

```
    public static void AutoTypeText(string Text)
    {
    Text = Regex.Replace(Text, “[+^%~()\\{\\}]”, “{$0}”);

      SendKeys.Send(Text);
    }
```

My Issue Is When I Send, Especially When I Attempt To Send A Caret ^ It Will Send The Caret But The Characters Afterward Are Set To Lowercase.

Example: ^ziFTKAyoVnoHXS

**Expected:**
^ziFTKAyoVnoHXS

**Results:**
^ziftkayovnohxs

How Can I Get My Expected Result Without Importing An External SendKeys Code From NuGet?

Comment: Can reproduce. One workaround was to send the caret in a separate call to `Send`.

Comment: No repro: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7GWy.gif